# Запрет нажатия ссылки js

Tags: javascript

На странице есть аудиоплеер с плейлистом, в котором каждый трек - ссылка `<a href="..." class="play-item">...</a>`, при нажатии на которую он играет. На странице есть ещё одна ссылка, для перехода на другую страницу, типа `<a href="..." class="readmore">Туда</a>`. Я хотел бы запретить нажатие ссылки `.readmore`, если не выбран трек в плейлисте, т.е., если не нажата ни одна ссылка `.play-item`. Как это сделать средствами js? Спасибо!

Comment: pointer-events: none пробовали?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ боюсь, это будет не кроссбраузерно

Comment: откуда такие опасения?

Answer (score 3):

Вот банально простой пример с использованием флагов.Для того чтобы просто понять суть.Если одно из элементов списка не нажато то красную кнопку либо ссылку нажать будет невозможно.

И `а` надо заменить на `span` ну или любой другой подходящий тег.

```js
const testEl = document.querySelectorAll(".test"),
   red = document.getElementById("red"),
   link = document.getElementById("link");
   
let flag = false;

link.onclick = _ => {
  flag ? window.location = "https://www.google.ru/" : null;
}

testEl.forEach(el => {
  el.onclick = _ => {
      flag !== true ? (flag = true , red.innerHTML = "Now clickable") : null;
  };
});

red.onclick = _ => {
  flag ? red.classList.add("red") : null;
}
```

```css
.red {
  background:red;
}
#link {
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="test">test 1</li>
    <li class="test">test 2</li>
    <li class="test">test 3</li>
</ul>

<button id="red">Not clickable</button>

<span id="link">link</span>
```